# Restrict LWC in Community Template Footer to Content Width

Tags: community, lightning-web-components

I'm currently creating a LWC which will actually be the footer of a couple of different Salesforce communities.

Within the community, I want to add it to the template footer so that all pages use the same footer.

However, I want to restrict the width of the actual footer to be the same as the content width that has been set (and not the full width of the browser).

Is there any way of doing this, or referencing that content width within the CSS for my LWC?